# What is the difference between a stationary and a non-stationary policy?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, policies, stationary-policy

In reinforcement learning, there are [deterministic and non-deterministic (or stochastic) policies](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12274/2444), but there are also *stationary* and *non-stationary* policies.

What is the difference between a stationary and a non-stationary policy? How do you formalize both? Which problems (or environments) require a stationary policy as opposed to a non-stationary one (and vice-versa)?

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) should also be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [**stationary policy**](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.516.4121&rep=rep1&type=pdf), $\pi_t$, is a policy that does not change over time, that is, $\pi_t = \pi, \forall t \geq 0$, where $\pi$ can either be a function, $\pi: S \rightarrow A$ (a deterministic policy), or a conditional density, $\pi(A \mid S)$ (a stochastic policy). A **non-stationary policy** is a policy that is **not** stationary. More precisely, $\pi_i$ may not be equal to $\pi_j$, for $i \neq j \geq 0$, where $i$ and $j$ are thus two different time steps.

There are problems where a stationary optimal policy is guaranteed to exist. For example, in the case of a stochastic (there is a probability density that models the dynamics of the environment, that is, the transition function and the reward function) and discrete-time Markov decision process (MDP) with finite numbers of states and actions, and bounded rewards, where the *objective* is the long-run average reward, a stationary optimal policy exists. The proof of this fact is in the book [*Markov Decision Processes: Discrete Stochastic Dynamic Programming*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316887) (1994), by Martin L. Puterman, which *apparently* is not freely available on the web.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116369/discussion-on-answer-by-nbro-what-is-the-difference-between-a-stationary-and-a-n).