# What is the equation for $\pi_*$ in terms of $q_*(s,a)$?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sutton-barto, policies, notation, optimality

I am trying to solve the following exercise from Sutton and Barto:

> Sutton and Barto Exercise 3.27 Give an equation for $\pi_*$ in terms of $q_*(s,a)$

However, I am struggling to do so. I know that $\pi_*$ is the policy which will pick the action with highest return, given we know what the optimal action values are. So intuitively, I would express the optimal policy like this: $$\pi_*(\text{argmax}_a q_*(s,a)|s) = 1$$. To express it like this: $$\pi_* = \text{argmax}_a q_*(s,a) $$

seems wrong since $\pi_*$ is a probability. What am I not getting correct here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optimal policy is just a greedy policy with respect to the optimal state-action value function (which is unique for a given MDP). So, $\pi_* = \text{argmax}_a q_*(s,a) $ is almost correct - it should have been

$$\pi_*(s) = \text{argmax}_a q_*(s,a), \forall s.$$

In this case, $\pi_*$ is a [decision rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_rule) or a function.

If you define $\pi^*$ as a [probability distribution](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12274/2444), then you can do something like this

$$
\pi_*(s, a)=
\begin{cases}
1, \text{if } a = \text{argmax}_a q_*(s,a)\\
0, \text{otherwise}\end{cases},
$$
$\forall s \in \mathcal{S}$.

If $\text{argmax}_a q_*(s,a)$ is a set, you can choose any of the actions in that set with any rule you want, and, of course, still ignore non-optimal actions.

This is true for finite MDPs (aka MDPs with finite state, action and reward spaces).

There's a result (Putterman, 1994) that states that there's a deterministic and Markovian optimal policy for an MDP. So, optimal policies aren't (necessarily) probability distributions. It's a matter of convention and convenience.

Comment: I am not sure the action and reward spaces need to be finite. Maybe you just need the rewards to be bounded and I am not sure about the action space. There are assumptions in that book, which I may check later. The specific theorem may be 6.2.7, and applies to infinite-horizon discounted MDPs with finite $\mathcal{S}$ (at least). One also requires stationary reward and transition functions.