# How are these two equations for the optimal state-value function equivalent?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, value-functions, bellman-equations, optimality

By substituting the optimal policy $\pi_{\star}$ into the Bellman equation, we get the Bellman equation for $v_{\pi_{\star}}(s)=v_{\star}(s)$:

$$ v_{\star}(s) = \sum\limits_a \pi_{\star}(a|s) \sum\limits_{s'} \sum_r p(s', r | s, a)[r + \gamma v_{\star}(s')]$$

From the above equation, how can we obtain the this one?

$$ v_{\star}(s) = \max\limits_a \sum\limits_{s'} \sum\limits_r p(s', r|s,a) [r + \gamma v_{\star}(s')]$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first equation is the definition of any state value function, so it must also be definition of the optimal state value function $v_*$.

The second equation is the definition of $v_*$ in terms of the state-action value function $\color{green}{q_*}$.

In reality, the first equation is also the definition of $v_*$ in terms of $\color{green}{q_*}$, which is what you want to see :)

First, note that

\begin{align}
v_\pi(s) 
&=
 \sum_a \pi(a \mid s) 
\color{blue}{\sum_{s'} \sum_r p(s', r|s, a) [r + \gamma v_\pi(s')]} \\
&= \sum_a \pi(a \mid s) \color{blue}{q_\pi(s, a)} \tag{1}\label{1}.
\end{align}
Now, we denote the optimal state value function as $v_{\pi_*} = v_*$. If we plug $v_*$, $\pi_*$ and $\color{green}{q_*}$ in the equation above, we get your first equation, but we write it as

\begin{align}
v_*(s) 
&= \sum_a \pi_*(a \mid s) \color{green}{q_*(s, a)} \tag{2}\label{2}.
\end{align}
For finite MDPs, the optimal policy is deterministic, i.e. it chooses one action (the optimal one) with probability $1$, so that means that \ref{2} can be written as

\begin{align}
v_*(s) 
&= 0 \color{green}{q_*(s, a_1)} + \cdots + 1 \color{green}{q_*(s, a_*)} + 0 \color{green}{q_*(s, a_N)} \\
&= \color{green}{q_*(s, a_*)} \\
&= \max_a \color{green}{q_*(s, a)} \\
&=\max_a \color{green}{ \sum_{s'} \sum\limits_r p(s', r|s,a) [r + \gamma v_{*}(s')]}
\tag{3}\label{3},
\end{align}
where $a_* = \text{argmax}_a\pi_*(a \mid s) = \text{argmax}_a \color{green}{q_*(s, a)}$ is the optimal action. By definition, the optimal action in state $s$ is the one that leads to the highest expected return. See also [this answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/36209/2444).

Finally, note that optimal value functions are unique for finite MPDs, so $\color{green}{q_*}$ and $v_*$ are unique.

Comment: still, there are some typos and unclear points: (1) $a_*$ is an action value and $\pi_{*}(s)$ is a probability value and hence they cannot be equal as you wrote in the bottom line. (2) why do we have $q_{*}(s,a_*)= \max_{a}q_{*}(s,a)?$

Comment: @DSPinfinity I used my notation inconsistently. If $\pi_*(s)$ is a probability distribution, then $\pi_*(s)$ would be a probability. However, there, I used $\pi_*$ to refer to a function (or decision rule) that is derived from the stochastic policy. $a_* = \text{argmax}_a \pi_*(s, a)$. $a_*$ is an action, not an action value, $q_*(s, a_*)$ would be the (action) value of $a_*$ in $s$. You have $q_*(s, a_*) = \max_a q_*(s, a)$ because the highest action value in state $s$ of the optimal value function is associated with the optimal action, $a_*$ That's the definition of the optimal action.

Comment: @DSPinfinity Maybe [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/36209/2444) can also help.