# What does the line of code "self.buffer[-1] = observation" do in this BufferWrapper class for DQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, dqn, gym, experience-replay

So the code is related to using a buffer

```
class BufferWrapper(gym.ObservationWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env, n_steps, dtype=np.int):
        super(BufferWrapper, self).__init__(env)
        self.dtype = dtype
        old_space = env.observation_space
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(old_space.low.repeat(n_steps, axis=0),
                                                old_space.high.repeat(n_steps, axis=0), dtype=dtype)

    def reset(self):
        self.buffer = np.zeros_like(self.observation_space.low, dtype=self.dtype)
        return self.observation(self.env.reset())

    def observation(self, observation):
        self.buffer[:-1] = self.buffer[1:]
        self.buffer[-1] = observation
        return self.buffer
```

It is used to basically do some image processing so that the DQN is fed some transformation of the image. This [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-q-network-dqn-i-bce08bdf2af) provides some higher-level logic behind some operations.

How can I actually understand what's the reason behind the code? Almost all repos have the exact same lines with no explanation (e.g. [atari games GitHub repo](https://github.com/hizircanbayram/FeDQN-A-Federated-Learning-Approach-for-Training-Reinforcement-Learning-Agent-of-Atari-Games/blob/main/FederatedRLPong.py)).

My specific question is what is the purpose of the line `self.buffer[-1] = observation`?

In my case, my observation is a (7*1) array and I have to return that in an appropriate manner from the `observation` function.

[The book](https://pytorch-lightning-bolts.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/0.1.1/pdf/) has some mention of this class but I couldn't understand much from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you're confused about this code because you're not very familiar with Python or reinforcement learning (specifically, DQN and **experience replay**), but that code should be very clear to you if you know Python, but maybe you're not very familiar with DQN.

Let's take a look at the `observation` method.

```
def observation(self, observation):
    self.buffer[:-1] = self.buffer[1:]
    self.buffer[-1] = observation
    return self.buffer
```

- `self.buffer[:-1] = self.buffer[1:]` essentially drops/forgets the first (which is also the oldest) observation in the buffer.
- `self.buffer[-1] = observation` adds the new `observation` (passed as parameter) as the last element of the buffer

You can execute the following code to see what that method does.

```
buffer = [10, 7, 3]
print(buffer)

buffer[:-1] = buffer[1:]

observation = 5
buffer[-1] = observation

print(buffer) # [7, 3, 5]
```

If you are not familiar with the **experience replay** technique, you can take a look at [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/11644/2444) or [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/24362/2444) answers.